# Showing a form in c# issue?

Tags: c#

I have 3 forms. `frm1`, `frm2` and `frm3`. I want to show `frm3` from `frm1` and `frm2` without creating the new instance of it. Just I want to show frm3 always the actual form not the new instance of it:

Example I have tried in Frm1:

```
frm3 f3 = new frm3()
f3.showDialog();
```

in Frm2:

```
frm3 f3 = new frm3();
f3.showDialog();
```

But I don't want to show `frm3` like I have tried, I want the actual form not the new instance?

Comment: make your answer clear and meaningful.

Comment: It isn't an answer it is a comment

Comment: comments also should be meaningful.

Comment: If you know the solution, provide it as an Answer, then it will be Accepted.

Comment: Are you looking for [show/hide optons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167625/way-to-quickly-show-hide-winforms-gui-c-sharp) ?

Comment: It sounds like you need a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx) but i'd be very wary about applying this to a form, what are the actual forms doing? (what is form3?) which one is the parent form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add a public property of type `frm3` to both `frm1` and `frm2`.

```
public frm3 Form3 {get; set;}
```

Then create an instance of `frm3` and  set the property on both frm1 and frm2 so that they can use the same instance.

e.g. in Sub Main

```
frm1 f1 = new frm1();
frm2 f2 = new frm2();
frm3 f3 = new frm3();

frm1.Form3 = f3;
frm2.Form3 = f3;
```

Then in frm2 and frm1 you can use

```
this.Form3.ShowDialog();
```

Note that you will need to be careful not to try to manipulate the instance of frm3 from both frm1 and frm2 at the same time. You will likely get errors.

Comment: Better add it to the constructor of frm1 and frm2

Comment: That would be an option, but not necessarily better. It depends on what your design goals/limitations are.

Comment: This really depends on which form is the parent form, if form3 isn't the parent then this will require adding a reference back to existing forms. But in essence... I do agree, preferably set the property in the base class or interface

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely dynamic without global vars or other constructions. Also don't have to change any of the current Form code.

```
public void CreateOrActivateForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    IEnumerable<T> openForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>();

    if (openForms.Any())
    {
        foreach (T openForm in openForms)
        {
            openForm.Activate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Form form = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        form.Show();
    }
}

public void OpenForm2()
{
    CreateOrActivateForm<Form2>();
}
```

Place this inside a 'Helper' class and you can activate open forms or create new ones.

If you only want to get 'Form2':

```
Form2 form2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Cast<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to have a new instance of your form every time you want to show it, you could, on your form1 have a global variable that you instansiate once on your form1 load, and then show it (frm2.showdialog) when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code.

Add constructor and getter method inside your form class.

```
public partial class YourFormClass: Form
{
    private static YourFormClass mInst;

    private YourFormClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static YourFormClass CheckInst
    {
        get
        {
            return mInst;
        }
    }

    public static YourFormClass CreateInst
    {
        get
        {
            if (mInst == null)
                mInst = new YourFormClass();
            return mInst;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        mInst = null;
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }

}
```

After that check the form instance already in use

```
if (YourFormClass.CheckInst == null)
{
    YourFormClass.CreateInst.Show();
    YourFormClass.CreateInst.MdiParent = this;
}
else
{
    YourFormClass.CreateInst.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    YourFormClass.CreateInst.Focus();
}
```

Check it once.